# Unexpected pop window handling while running script in selenium web driver using java

Tags: eclipse, selenium-webdriver

https://uk.support.tomtom.com/app/ when I go here, after 70 or 80 seconds, a pop-up window appears(survey window), and my code always fails because it does not execute the next line. I want that whenever that pop-up window comes up during my program flow it should get handled. this pop-up window comes on every page, so If I miss to cancel or accept it on the main page it will appear to next redirected page after few seconds. So how I can handle this situation. I don't know when that pop-up window will appear.

My Code is

```
public class stackoverflow {
    public WebDriver driver ; 
    String driverPath = "C:\\Users\\******\\Desktop\\chromedriver_win32 (1)\\chromedriver.exe"; //driver path

  @Test
  public void f() {
      System.out.println("launching chrome browser"); //print launch browser
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",driverPath); //call driver path
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize(); //Maximising the window
        driver.manage().deleteAllCookies(); ///clearing browser cookies
        driver.get("https://uk.support.tomtom.com/app/"); //getting url
        driver.navigate().to("http://uk.support.tomtom.com/app/contact/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(61,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='rnDialog1_c']")).click(); //click on survey window
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[text()='Cancel']")).click(); //click on survey window cancel button

  }
}
```

I dont know if you also get survey window or not.

Comment: by pop up do you mean the button to accept cookies?

Comment: No, not the cookie one, I am getting survey window pop up in the middle of the screen with Cancel and accept button. I don't know how to insert an image in comment box otherwise I can show you that.

Comment: yeah I see it now.. does it come everytime? or sometimes?

Comment: it seems if you stay in page for 5 or 6 min, it comes up again. Either this survey comes up or page expired pop up box comes up.

Comment: You could actually write a function which will check if this element is visible or not (survey popup buttons). and call it between operations.. Once it appears and is handled you can stop checking for that element..

Comment: moreover I feel this appears when the site is left idle.. try not to leave it idle. or whenever it is left idle check for this survey buttons before continuing..

Comment: I try writing element visible function and see if that works.

Comment: sure.. use "driver.switchTo().alert().dismiss();" to cancel the survey and continue with your execution.

Answer (score 0):

Most surveys like this are tied to a cookie that is created after the survey is either dismissed or completed. Figure out which cookie is created once the survey is dismissed and then create that cookie at the start of your test. No more prompts...